# Javascript DataSet

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function fetchJobs()
{
var seq_id = 2;
var dataset = [{"seq_id":"1","counter":"20"},{"seq_id":"2","counter":21"}]
}
```

May I ask how do I get value 21 if my seq_id is **2**
and if my seq id is 1, I want to get the value 20, which is the counter value

How do I get the value of counter: based on the value of seq_id:

Comment: You would have to loop through the array and read the value for the object in each index.

Comment: Justin is correct, his 1st suggestion is the easiest, but it would be even nicer if you redesign your dataset, so that you have `seq_id` as key and the objects as values, this would give fast access. e.g. `dataset[seq_id] = {counter: 20, ...}`, no loop, no find required, just simple access.

Comment: if your sequence has no gaps, you could already do it now: `dataset[seq_id - 1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of three options:

1. A traditional for loop over the `dataset` collection. Check each element as you loop and break once you find the value.
2. Use [`Array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if available, or use the Polyfill from MDN's documentation.
3. Try something like [LINQ to JavaScript](https://jslinq.codeplex.com/) (definitely overkill if this is all you need it for).

Comment: I went for approach 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
function fetchJobs()
{
    var seq_id = 2;
    var dataset = [{"seq_id":"1","counter":"20"},{"seq_id":"2","counter":"21"}]
    var output = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++){
        if(dataset[i]['seq_id'] == seq_id){
            output = dataset[i]['counter'].toString();
        }
    }
    console.log(output); //Or do whatever
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Note, appear missing `"` before `21` at `{"seq_id":"2","counter":21"}`

Try utilizing `$.grep()`

```js
var dataset = [{
  "seq_id": "1",
  "counter": "20"
}, {
  "seq_id": "2",
  "counter": "21"
}];

var filtered = function(id) {
  return $.grep(dataset, function(val, key) {
    return val.seq_id === id
  })[0].counter
};
console.log(filtered("1"), filtered("2"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```